# 'rasa' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

Issue is :
I have created an environment with name rasa and python version 3.6: after that, I activated that environment, then started with pip install rasa > after that it is saying requirements already satisfied.
After this, I wrote rasa init command but it shows error: 'rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

where i went wrong???

Comment: Could you update your question with the commands you ran & their output? Also, what is the output of `pip list | grep rasa`?

Comment: conda create -n rasa python==3.6 anaconda           then       activate rasa(environment name)    then        pip install rasa   (here it says requirement already satisfied)      after that i wrote rasa init   (here it says no such command)

Answer (score 0):

This seems rasa is already installed in the conda environment and that could have not properly install etc or similar issues.

Follow the following and let me know if it works for you.

`conda create --name  rasa_project     #new virtual env. created`

`conda activate rasa_project           # activated the virtual env.`

`pip3 install rasa                     # installed rasa python version 3 here`

Comment: I have installed it earlier as you mentioned, so I created a new environment did your steps and again I initialised rasa, same query.

Comment: rasa is not recognized as internal and external command.

Comment: Could you share details about OS?

Comment: windows 10,64-bit.

Comment: Alright - my first advice - try to work with Linux if possible to bypass future issues of rasa :) Second - to solve your current problem.1) Try setting the Python path in Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables. (ideally we want it in a top-level folder)

Comment: 2) Re-install Python using the graphical installer. Run the regular Python installer as administrator. BE SURE to click the little ‘Add to PATH’ checkbox, or all this will be for naught!! (For me personally this is a lot easier than manually adjusting the path in environment variables.) Then choose "Custom install location." Clicking "Install for all users" should automatically change the install path to the C:Program Files folder.

Comment: 3) You may also be able to do this without a full reinstall by selecting Programs > Programs and Features > Modify/Repair. [This will do the job for you- just let me know how it went!!] [Refernce link - https://www.thetopsites.net/article/59880260.shtml#:~:text=Menu-,'rasa'%20is%20not%20recognized%20as%20an%20internal%20or%20external%20command,operable%20program%20or%20batch%20file&text=3)%20You%20may%20also%20be,and%20Features%20%3E%20Modify%2FRepair%20.]

Comment: Thanks for the help, will definitely try.

Comment: Glad to know. Please consider up voting and select it as correct answer.

Comment: I already voted but it is not not displaying in public

Comment: Could you just try now, one more time? Also, you can upvote the comments which I have used for answering the problem  :)